# Adjusting Trigger to cope with more than one row in inserted/deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have recently learnt that trigger (inserted/deleted) tables can contain more than one row and so have revisited my triggers to make sure that they will cope with this. Most will but I'm not sure about this one... On updating the trigger will execute USP_UpdateASR (a CLR stored proc if that has any bearing) either once, twice or not at all dependant on the value of rAssigneeID.

Will this trigger cope if there is more than one row in inserted/deleted? If not what are my best options to fix this?

```
    USE [NW_Scheduler]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[OnUpdateTriggerUSP_UpdateASR]    Script Date: 21/04/2021 10:09:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Mychajlo M Dubil
-- Create date: 31/01/2021
-- Description: On Updating TblRequests need to trigger
--              USP_UpdateASR so that the corresponding
--              record in tblAvailabilitySummary is also
--              updated.
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[OnUpdateTriggerUSP_UpdateASR] 
   ON  [dbo].[tblRequests] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    
    DECLARE @PrevUserID INT
    DECLARE @PrevLogDate Date
    DECLARE @UserID INT
    DECLARE @LogDate Date   
    SELECT @PrevUserID = deleted.rAssigneeID FROM deleted
    SELECT @PrevLogDate = CONVERT(DATE, deleted.rStart) FROM deleted
    SELECT @UserID = inserted.rAssigneeID FROM inserted
    SELECT @LogDate = CONVERT(DATE, inserted.rStart) FROM inserted

    --IF @UserID <= 0 OR @PrevUserID <= 0 Then we can
    --skip EXEC USP_UpdateASR as the User is a PseudoUser
    IF @PrevUserID > 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC USP_UpdateASR @PrevLogDate, @PrevUserID
        END
    IF @UserID >0
        BEGIN
            EXEC USP_UpdateASR @LogDate, @UserID
        END

END
```

Comment: No, your trigger is severly flawed as it *assumes* a `UPDATE` can only effect one row; this is simply not true. Have a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: Also, however, a `TRIGGER` should have as *minimal* impact as possible. Executing a Procedure inside a `TRIGGER` is unlikely to achieve that. Most likely this is logic that should be outside of a trigger, not in one.

Comment: No, this trigger will not work if any more than a single row is updated. If you update 2 or 200 rows, only data from ONE row will ever be used. This is not a good use-case for a trigger.

Comment: Best option to fix this is to incorporate what the `USP_UpdateASR` is doing into the trigger.

Comment: Is you're calling a CLR procedure if you can't reproduce its logic in the trigger then you need to pass a table-valued parameter to the procedure and have the procedure work on a set of values.

Comment: I agree with @Squirrel your best option is to move the `usp_UpdateASR` code into the trigger to use the inserted/deleted virtual tables directly. Your other option is to create a table type matching the `tblRequests` schema and insert the inserted/deleted rows into table variables of that type and pass those as table-valued parameters to a refactored version of the proc.

Comment: Can `USP_UpdateASR` take a TVP, or perhaps it can be refactored to a Table-Valued Function, then you can `CROSS APPLY` it, what does it do?

Comment: However, if you have no choice but to continue on this path, bad though it maybe, you solve your issue by looping through all the inserted records, and all the deleted records, calling your SP once per record. You can use a cursor, a table variable loop or a temp table loop. Opinions differ as to which is best.

Comment: I'm not sure that USP_UpdateASR can be incorporated into a trigger it contains functions that I am competent to write in VB.Net but not sure if all is possible in SQL. Basically TblRequests contains records that relate to an event on a scheduler. These are either assigned to a user or unallocated. TblAvailabilitySummary contains a row per user per day which summarises all events for a user for that day totalling up the durations based on event categories and calculating the 'availability' based on the time the user is scheduled to book on that date. Continued on next comment...

Comment: I have three triggers:
OnInsert will update the record in tblAvailabilitySummary for the user/day in question and recalculate the availability. If no record for user/day is found a new record is created.
OnDelete will update the record in tblAvailabilitySummary by recalculating the availability for the user/day in question
OnUpdate will do a combination of things as the event may have been reassigned to another user (in which case bot users records need amending) or from an unallocated state to a user and/or may have moved from one day to another in which both date records need ammending.